Looking for a desktop-based collaborative TeX editor
I have been a long-time Overleaf user until I tried to compile a 50-page document 10 minutes before a project report deadline that was full of TikZ and CircuiTikZ diagrams. I had to get myself a free trial to have the thing compile and it still took ages. Nothing against Overleaf, brilliant site, but it seems I have progressed beyond its free capabilities.
I'm looking for a cross-platform TeX editor that I can work collaboratively on with multiple users. I'm not looking for paid software. Is VSCode the best option, or does someone have some good alternatives?

what do you mean by 'collaborative'? if you use overleaf, you and your collaborators all have access to the project files on the remote server. if you install locally, you and your collaborators each have a separate copy of the project. the main question you have to answer is how you are going to coordinate your efforts. you can use which editor you prefer - as can each of your collaborators. if you like vs code, use that. if your colleagues prefer vim or kile, they can use vim or kile. tht's fine. but if you each edit a copy of the project with no coordination, you'll have three projects.

Coordinate efforts in the sense that if I use VSCode, I'd set up a Git repo for the project. If I'm editing a document in Word, for example, it can be live edited by multiple people (this is what I would prefer). The problem with Overleaf is that when the file is large, the compile times are ridiculous (+ it's expensive). I'm looking for an editor that can compile locally on my machine, but have the code be live updated by multiple users without having to use Git.

so you are looking to run a server so they can access the file on your machine? you can, in fact, install overleaf locally - or, at least, something very like it. (I don't know if the open source version is 100% alike.) https://github.com/overleaf

Compile time won't get much faster on other systems. Complex tikz graphics need time. Beside this:  For small projects you can find free trial options for lots of things, but for large projects you have to pay for such services, either in money or by spending your time to setup and maintain a collaboration service. Why do expect to get this all for free?
